# MongoDB in Go (golang) with mgo: how to use logical operators to query?

Tags: mongodb, go, match, logical-operators, mgo

I would like to run the following query in golang using mgo in a pipeline.

```
{"key1" : 1,
 "$or" : [{"key2" : 2}, {"key3" : 2}]}
```

I have looked everywhere, but I cannot find an example like this. I have tried many different combinations, for example:

```
...
pipeline := []bson.M{
                     bson.M{    "$match" :  bson.M{ "key1" : 1,  
                                                   "$or" : bson.M{ "key2" : 2, "key3" : 2},
                     }
                     ...
            }
```

which compiles correctly, does not find anything. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your mongo query can be translated to the following:

```
pipeline := bson.D{
    {"key1", 1},
    {"$or", []interface{}{
        bson.D{{"key2", 2}},
        bson.D{{"key3", 2}},
    }},
}
```

The query should be equivalent to the following in the mongo console:

```
db.mycollection.find({"key1" : 1, "$or" : [{"key2" : 2}, {"key3" : 2}]})
```

If you'd rather wish to use unordered maps, `bson.M`, it would be like this:

```
pipeline := bson.M{
    "key1": 1,
    "$or": []interface{}{
        bson.M{"key2": 2},
        bson.M{"key3": 2},
    },
}
```

Comment: Welcome! You missed the array/slice, so the key was []interface{}

Comment: I copy pasted your bson.D example and I get "exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field."

Comment: @FuriousGeorge Are you using the query in a `Find` or `Pipe`? The error is a mongodb one, but I haven't played so much with building aggregation pipelines, so I can't tell you right away how to fix it. Sorry.

Comment: pipe := collection.Pipe(pipeline)

 if error := pipe.All(&res); error != nil {
  t.Fatal(error)
 }

Comment: Hey, why we cannot using `bson.D` for `[]interface{}`? I guess it's the same thing, right? I've tried it, but It seems the query is not working as expected. Any reason?

Comment: Oh sorry, stupid question. `bson.D` is not `[]interface{}`, `bson.A` does. If we're using `bson.D` instead of `[]interface{}` (since `bson.D` is `[]bson.E`, can't have `bson.D` or `bson.M` inside `bson.D`), then the structure would be different, hence the query will not working.

Answer (score 1):

> go lang Mongo db Or query

```
findQuery := bson.M{"key1" : 1}
orQuery := []bson.M{}
orQuery := append(orQuery, bson.M{"key2" : 2}, bson.M{"key3" : 2})

findquery["$or"] = orQuery
result := []interface{}
err := mongo.DB.C("collectionName").find(findQuery).All(&result)
```