# MongoDB in Go with mgo, operators with bson.M / bson.D always got syntax error

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

It is kind of stupid syntax error, tried tons of ways, just couldn't get it work, someone please help.

MongoDB in Go with `mgo`, I just tried to simplify use the `$ne` operator, code like below, but kept getting compile syntax error:

```
line 15: convIter := Session.Copy().DB("").C("convs").Find(bson.M {
line 16:   "conversationStatus": interface{} {
line 17:     bson.M {
line 18:       "$ne": "DESTROYED"
line 19:     },
line 20:   },
line 21: }).Iter()
```

Tried to add comma `,` remove comma everywhere, just couldn't get it work, always got such compile syntax error like below:

```
mongodb/query.go:16: syntax error: unexpected {, expecting comma or }
mongodb/query.go:20: syntax error: unexpected }, expecting expression
mongodb/query.go:21: syntax error: unexpected }, expecting expression
```

Comment: have you tried to add `,` at the end of the line `18` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#M) is a map type, so the `bson.M{ ... }` is a [map literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals). If key-value pairs are written in multiple rows, each has to end with a comma. For details, see [How to break a long line of code in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846848/how-to-break-a-long-line-of-code-in-golang/34848928#34848928)

Also there is no "interface" literal, drop that. A value of `interface{}` type can hold / wrap any value, including a `bson.M` value. And the `interface{}` value creation is automatic, you don't even need a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

Correct syntax:

```
convIter := Session.Copy().DB("").C("convs").Find(bson.M{
    "conversationStatus": bson.M{
        "$ne": "DESTROYED",
    },
}).Iter()
```

Similarly, if you use the [`bson.D`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#D) type (which is a slice), lines not ending with the closing bracket of the literal has to end with a comma, e.g.:

```
d := bson.D{
    {Name: "fieldA", Value: 1},
    {Name: "fieldB", Value: "running"},
}
```

Comment: thank u very much for ur super quick answer, yea, it works.

Comment: i saw another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932298/mongodb-in-go-golang-with-mgo-how-to-use-logical-operators-to-query , when the filed need to be used with slice, then the answer showed the correct way is: `"$or": []interface{} {bson.M{"key2": 2}, bson.M{"key3": 2},},`, if don't use the `interface` literal, what is the correct way to do that?

Comment: @lnshi When you need to create a _slice_ whose type is `[]interface{}`, then you need to state the slice type in the literal, e.g. `[]interface{}{1, "two"}`. But in your case you're not creating a slice, only a _single value_, of which the `interface{}` value creation is automatic, as stated in the answer.